# Wait until the proper item is added to a queue

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

This is not strictly correct put pretend it is. In a live poker game you are not allowed to bet out of turn.  Online you are allowed to bet out of turn as no one can see you.  The server just queues up the bet and processes it when it is your turn.  When it is your turn if you have not queued a bet then the server will wait x second for you to bet or fold you out (eliminate).

In this simulation `pp3` does not queue up a bet so when it is their turn there is no bet.  `WaitFor` is called.  Even with `clearToGo` == false `WaitFor` still calls return.

I need `WaitFor` to wait `clearToGo` to be true before returning.  Even if `clearToGo` is false I need it to return after x seconds.

A bool `clearToGo` may not be the proper approach.  Or other stuff may not be the proper approach.  I want to show that I have tired.

**How can the the server let a player bet in advance and if they don't bet in advance only give them x second before ignoring them?**

```
public class PkrTable 
{
    List<PkrAction> pkrActions = new List<Program.PkrAction>();
    List<PkrPlayer> pkrPlayers = new List<PkrPlayer>();
    public void SbmtAction (PkrAction pkrAction)
    {
        if (!BeenWaitinOnYou(pkrAction))
        {
            pkrActions.Add(pkrAction);
        }
    }
    private void ProcessAction(PkrAction pkrAction)
    {
        //process               
    }
    private bool BeenWaitinOnYou(PkrAction pkrAction)
    {
        if(waitingOn != null && waitingOn == pkrAction.PkrPlayer)
        {
            ProcessAction(pkrAction);
            //this is where WaitFor can return
            clearToGo = true; 
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    private PkrPlayer waitingOn = null;
    private bool clearToGo = false;
    private async Task WaitFor()
    {
        if (clearToGo)
        {
            waitingOn = null;
            return;
            //problem is this returns even if clearToGo is flase 
            //even if clearToGo is false I need to return in x seconds
        }
    }
    private async Task ProcessQueue()
    {
        foreach(PkrPlayer pp in pkrPlayers)
        {
            PkrAction pa = pkrActions.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PkrPlayer == pp);
            if(pa == null)
            {
                waitingOn = pp;
                clearToGo = false;
                await WaitFor(); 
            }
            else
            {
                ProcessAction(pa); 
                pkrActions.Remove(pa);                      
            }
        }
    }
    public PkrTable()
    {
        PkrPlayer pp = new PkrPlayer(1, this);
        pp.SbmtAction(12);
        pkrPlayers.Add(pp);
        pp = new PkrPlayer(2, this);
        pp.SbmtAction(12);
        pkrPlayers.Add(pp);
        PkrPlayer pp3 = new PkrPlayer(3, this);
        pkrPlayers.Add(pp3);
        pp = new PkrPlayer(4, this);
        pp.SbmtAction(12);
        pkrPlayers.Add(pp);

        ProcessQueue();
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        pp3.SbmtAction(14);               
    }

}
public class PkrAction
{
    public PkrPlayer PkrPlayer { get; }
    public int Amt { get; }
    public PkrAction(PkrPlayer pkrPlayer, int amt)
    {
        PkrPlayer = pkrPlayer;
        Amt = amt;
    }
}
public class PkrPlayer
{
    private PkrTable pkrTable;
    public int ID { get; }

    public void SbmtAction(int amount)
    {
        PkrAction pa = new PkrAction(this, amount);
        pkrTable.SbmtAction(pa);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ID;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is PokerPlayer))
            return false;
        else
            return ID == ((PokerPlayer)obj).ID;
    }
    public PkrPlayer(int id, PkrTable _pkrTable)
    {
        ID = id;
        pkrTable = _pkrTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a `while` loop in `WaitFor` that checks your bool, and a second async method that counts your x seconds and then updates the bool?

Comment: pass in a `CancellationToken`, you can wait on the handle - you can even automatically cancel it after a specific timespan and then check if a bet was made. Semantially a Auto-/ManualResetEvent would probably be more appropriate

Comment: @tim I am afraid a while loop would block from submitting.

Comment: @DennisKuypers I kind of get what you are saying. If it runs no matter what how does a CancellationToken let me stop it.

Comment: For CancellationTokens (that i have to wait on a lot) i made an extension method. Maybe it's useful to you: https://gist.github.com/denkuy/0362bfa38726681ddac815abf51e9b60

Comment: create a cancellationtokensource and pass the .Token to the waiting method. then wait on this. The extension method tells you if the token was cancelled or not. You can act on that (cancelled = user placed a bet, not cancelled = no action from user)